# Multiplying hexadecimal numbers in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

**A short version:** how do I multiply hexadecimal numbers with asm, where will the result be stored and how do I access it and move it to the `eax` register?

**A longer version**, which explains why would I need to do that and in which format:

I'd like to have a byte array which stores ASCII codes of some characters I'm going to output into the video memory. I can output two characters like this:

```
org 100 h

start:
    mov ax, 0003h
    int 10h

    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    mov di, 100
    mov eax, 1f651f48h
    stosd

    ret
```

This will output `He` in white letters on blue background to somewhere around the upper left corner of the screen. But I'd like to print 'Hello world!'. So I thought I'd store symbol codes in an array, form hexadecimal numbers like `1f651f48h` by addition and multiplication and output them by using `rep` command for a loop.

But I don't understand how to form such hexadecimal numbers. I don't really understand if the numbers I'm using here would need to be in `eax` or `ax`, or how do I fetch the result. So I'd like to request some explanations.

How this number works: `1f` is an attribute, this is for white letters on blue background. `65` is the ASCII code for `e`, `48` is for `h`. So I'd need to multiply 48 by 10000 (all numbers are hexadecimal) and add to `1f001f00h`, then add 65 to the result of the previous actions and move it all to the `eax` register.

I'm also confused about the use of the registers. The `cx` register is used for, so to say, 'loop iterations'; `bx` will be used for iterating over the array; the resulting number needs to be put in `eax`. This leaves me with nothing but `edx` for interim calculations, is it possible to do the things I need with only this?

I'm using NASM under a freedos emulation in qemu.

Comment: You also have `esi`, `edi` and `ebp`. Anyway, what you are trying to do is a simple `memcpy`, you only need a `rep movsw` for it. Also, `nasm` is quite capable to give you ascii codes, so you can do stuff like `db 'H', 0x1f, 'e', 0x1f, ...`

Comment: @Jester could you please explain in more detail? I'm very new to asm. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part do you want explained? About `rep movsw` consult an instruction set reference.

Comment: @Jester the last part, about `db 'H', 0x1f`, please.

Comment: That was just an illustration that you don't have to convert the ascii codes by hand, since `nasm` can do that. So you only need to list the characters and the attributes one after another.

Comment: @Jester ok, so I can create an array by using db and listing the characters and the attributes, but how do I get a number from this array? I take the first item, put it into some register, take the second item, put it into some other register, put 0x10000 or other number for interim calculations into some other register, do multiplication (how do I fetch the result? One part is in `eax`, other in `edx`, this is confusing), then addition, then repeat? Or how do I do that? Also I've read about `movsw` but I don't understand what would I use it for. Sorry for all these questions and thank you.

Comment: You don't have to do any calculation, you just need to copy the array into video memory. For that you can use the `rep movsw`. Set up `ds:si` to point to your array, `es:di` to point into the video memory and `cx` to contain number of characters.  You can of course also write it out as a loop, just load each word into a register and write it out.

Comment: one misunderstanding in your original question: `stosd` is similar to `mov [es:edi],eax` `add edi,4`, i.e. `eax` value is stored into memory. And `eax` is 32 bit register, 32 bits are stored into memory as 4x8 bits, i.e. 4 bytes. The VGA card in text mode reads video memory as series of bytes, first is letter, second is attribute, 160 bytes (80x[letter,attr]) per line (in 80x25 mode). So if you store `eax` into video RAM, you can write two letter with two attributes. If you would multiply that constant by something, it would reach value which can't fit into 32 bits, and it would be truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How this number works: 1f is an attribute, this is for white letters on blue background. 65 is the ASCII code for e, 48 is for h. So I'd need to multiply 48 by 10000 (all numbers are hexadecimal) and add to 1f001f00h, then add 65 to the result of the previous actions and move it all to the eax register.

If you were to follow this calculation you'd see on screen a WhiteOnBlue "eH", not the "He" that you expect!

The good news here is that you don't need any calculations to display the text.
Just define the message and then in a loop get a single character from it and put it on the screen.
Since this is a .COM file (`org 100h`), the `DS` segment register is already setup correctly.

```
org 100h

start:
    mov ax, 0003h  ;Text video mode 80x25
    int 10h

    mov ax, 0B800h ;Segment of video memory
    mov es, ax
    mov di, 100    ;Address in video memory
    cld        
    mov si, msg    ;Where is the message
Again:
    lodsb          ;Get 1 character into AL
    cmp al, 0      ;Is it terminating zero?
    je  EndOfLoop  ;Yes
    mov ah,1Fh     ;Combine with attribute
    stosw          ;Store AX in video memory
    jmp Again      ;Continu the loop
EndOfLoop:
    ret

msg db 'Hello world!',0
```